# symphony lib and headers for debian to install Rsymphony

Tags: r, debian

I want to install the `Rsymphony` package in R 3.1. While installing the following error is thrown:

`* package ‘Rsymphony’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
Cannot find SYMPHONY libraries and headers.
See <https://projects.coin-or.org/SYMPHONY>.
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘Rsymphony’`

So that decided to install the lib's for debian:

`apt-get install coinor-libsymphony-dev coinor-libsymphony-doc`

However, I still get the same error. Either I missed a certain lib or installed the wrong thing. How can I install the `Rsymphony` package correctly?

Spec: I'm using R 3.1 and debian 7.8

Answer (score 9):

You may need more libraries -- the [r-cran-rsymphony package](https://packages.debian.org/sid/r-cran-rsymphony) which I maintain has

```
Build-Depends: debhelper (>= 7.0.0), r-base-dev (>= 3.1.2), \
   cdbs, coinor-libsymphony-dev, coinor-libcgl-dev, autotools-dev
```

You can ignore `cdbs` etc if you are not building a package, but you probably want the two `coinor-*-dev` packages.

Comment: Many thanks for the quick responds. I addtionally installed the coinor-libcgl-dev package. However, I still get the error message `Cannot find SYMPHONY libraries and headers` when installing the `Rsymphony` packages. What could cause the problem?

Comment: I have no idea. I provide the package so that folks who can't install this themselves have something to fallback onto.  Check your configure logs, install missing packages. To reiterate: what I posted *works for all of Debian's autobuilders* but you may be on an older release--you did not say.

Comment: the strange thing is, I can use the `SYMPHONY-5-6-6` solver via the command line and solve sample problems without any issue. So it seems to me that the installation was successful.

Comment: In 16.10 Yakkety AMD64: depends: `coinor-libsymphony3` `libc6`(>=2.4) `r-base-core`(>=3.2.5-1) `r-api-3` `r-cran-symphony` with suggested: `r-cran-runit` but `r-api-3` seems to conflict

Comment: I'm on OSX and have Symphony installed but Rsymphony still can't find the libraries and headers. Any suggestions?

Comment: Besides carefully looking at what configure does and checking each requirement, no.

Comment: This worked for me: `sudo apt-get install coinor-libcgl-dev coinor-libsymphony-dev coinor-libsymphony-doc` Then used install.packages as usual.

Comment: Sure. But circular reasoning.  We have a (Debian) package for that. It needs to build.  So it has build-depends declared.  So you just copied those to build the package from source.  You could also have installed the binaries, or (useful trick!) have apt install the build-depends for said package for you.

Answer (score 4):

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 and R 3.1. I wanted to update package `Rsymphony` to version `0.1-19` and got a similar error message as above.

Following Dirk's advise I did `apt-get install coinor-libcgl-dev` which also installed `coinor-libclp-dev`, `coinor-libcoinutils-dev` and `coinor-libosi-dev`. After that I could install `Rsymphony` using R's installation mechanism.

`apt-get install r-cran-rsymphony` worked but installed version `0.1-17-1`.

Comment: I'll be more clear then: I wanted to share the fact that installing the library Dirk advised (coinor-libcgl-dev) also installed three additional libraries which were not mentioned before and may not be installed on user8's system. One or all of them might be needed for the installation of the latest version of the Rsymphony package. At least it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Please install the packages for the library first:

apt-get install coinor-libsymphony-dev coinor-libsymphony-doc

Then install the package from CRAN:

apt-get install r-cran-rsymphony

That did the trick for me:

[Sun|11:39:13][tir on atlas2:~]-> sudo apt-get install r-cran-rsymphony
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Suggested packages:
  r-cran-runit
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  r-cran-rsymphony
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 17 not upgraded.
Need to get 1,748 kB of archives.
After this operation, 3,919 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe r-cran-rsymphony amd64 0.1-17-1 [1,748 kB]
Fetched 1,748 kB in 54s (32.1 kB/s)
Selecting previously unselected package r-cran-rsymphony.
(Reading database ... 348392 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../r-cran-rsymphony_0.1-17-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking r-cran-rsymphony (0.1-17-1) ...
Setting up r-cran-rsymphony (0.1-17-1) ...
[Sun|11:40:26][tir on atlas2:~]->

Comment: thanks for your answer. I already tried this one and got the following error message in R: > library("Rsymphony", lib.loc="/usr/lib/R/site-library")
Error: package ‘Rsymphony’ was built before R 3.0.0: please re-install it